# Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'fileContent' of type 'Blob'

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, csv

So, I'm trying to pass a csv file to apex, with a lightning input type file and a button with an onclick that calls to the apex method, receiving a blob variable:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String processTracking(Blob fileContent, String separadorCsv){
    ApexLogger.debug('separadorCsv elegido =====> ' + separadorCsv);
    
    String[] lines = fileContent.toString().split('\n');
    String result;

    if(lines.size() > 0){
        result = processLines(lines, separadorCsv);
    }else{
        AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('El archivo debe tener al menos 2 líneas');
        e.setMessage('El archivo debe tener al menos 2 líneas');
        throw e;
    }

    return result;
}
```

this is the js method that makes the call to apex:

```
process(){
    if(this.file){
        this.pendingAction = processTracking({fileContent: this.file, separadorCsv: this.separadorCsv}).then(r =>{
            console.log('r => ' + r);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error =>', error);
            this.showMessage('Error en el proceso', error.message, 'error');
        })
    }else{
        this.showMessage('Error', 'No hay ningun archivo seleccionado', 'warning');
    }
}
```

the mime type of the csv file I created to test the component, is 'application/vnd.ms-excel'. I don't know if this is the problem or not, but it is a simple csv file I created manually. Do I have to change the MIME type or it's something else?